# Callback data is not being recognized

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, json

I am trying to delete this entire row whenever you click the Delete button. This is my jQuery command:

UPDATE: I have updated the click function to my finalized version:

```
$(document).on('click', '.delete-assignment',function () {
    console.log("click");
    var data = {
        assignment_id: $(this).closest('tr').find('.assignment-id').html(),
        class_id: $('#classId').val()
    }

    var row = $(this).closest('tr');

    deleteAssignment(data, function(returnData){
        var returnData = JSON.parse(returnData);

        if(returnData.status == "Success"){
            console.log("yes");
            row.hide();
        }
    });
});
```

When I click delete, it triggers the deleteAssignment function successfully and returns a callback of {"status":"Success"}. Yet when I returnData.status == "Success" is not being triggered.If I try jQuery.type(returnData), It says string. So I implemented JSON.parse and it says unexpected token in json at position 0

here is my html:

```
<tbody id="Homework">
    <tr>
        <td><a href="/class/assignment/view/51">Homework Test Title</a></td>
        <td>02/16/2017 - 10:00 AM</td>
        <td class="assignment-id">51</td>
        <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-danger delete-assignment">Delete</button></td>     
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

I wanted to also include how I am passing data back to deleteAssignment as a callback (defined in the javascript function (deleteAssignment)

```
assignment = Assignments.objects.get(id=data['assignment_id'])
        assignment.delete()

        data = {}
        data['status'] = "Success"

        return HttpResponse(json.dumps(data), content_type="application/json")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a clouser problem.

The variable `this` inside your callback function is not the same `this` that inside the `click` function.

There are several ways to solve this, here is one of them:

```
$('.delete-assignment').on('click', function () {

        var data = {
            assignment_id: $(this).closest('tr').find('.assignment-id').html(),
            class_id: $('#classId').val()
        }
        var that = this;

        deleteAssignment(data, function(returnData){
            console.log(returnData); 
            if(returnData.status == "Success"){
               print("yes");
                $(that).closest('tr').remove();
        }
    });
});
```